# Php xml how to create/add attribute xsi:nil="true"

Tags: php, xml, xml-nil

Trying to get such output

```
<DeclarationFile>
<Declaration Id="DEC">
<DokPVNv4>
<ParskMen>5</ParskMen>
<ParskCeturksnis xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Can not create `<ParskCeturksnis xsi:nil="true"/>`

If use just

```
$ParskCeturksnis = new SimpleXMLElement("<ParskCeturksnis></ParskCeturksnis>");
$ParskCeturksnis->addAttribute("xsi:nil", "true", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
echo $ParskCeturksnis->asXml();
```

all works

But if whole code

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

$DeclarationFile = $DOM->createElement('DeclarationFile');
$DOM->appendChild($DeclarationFile);

$Declaration = $DOM->createElement('Declaration');
$DeclarationFile->appendChild($Declaration);
$Declaration_att = $DOM->createAttribute('Id');
$Declaration->appendChild($Declaration_att);
$att_Declaration_text = $DOM->createTextNode('DEC');
$Declaration_att->appendChild($att_Declaration_text);

$DokPVNv4 = $DOM->createElement('DokPVNv4');
$Declaration->appendChild($DokPVNv4);

$ParskMen = '5';
$ParskMen = $DOM->createElement('ParskMen',mb_convert_encoding($ParskMen, "UTF-8") );
$DokPVNv4->appendChild($ParskMen);

$ParskCeturksnis = new SimpleXMLElement("<ParskCeturksnis></ParskCeturksnis>");
$ParskCeturksnis->addAttribute("xsi:nil", "true", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
echo $ParskCeturksnis->asXml();

echo $DOM->saveXML();
```

get error `XML Parsing Error: junk after document element`

Searched google, but have not found solution....

Tried

```
 $ParskCeturksnis = $DOM->createElement('ParskCeturksnis');
 $DokPVNv4->appendChild($ParskCeturksnis)->addAttribute("xsi:nil", "true", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

get `XML Parsing Error: no element found`

Comment: In your first version of the whole code, you are simply `echo`ing two separate XML documents (one created with SimpleXML, one created with DOM). PHP has no way of knowing how you want to combine them. Your second version of the code is using `->addAttribute()` on a DOM node, but this is part of the separate SimpleXML API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the SimpleXML and DOM extensions. While they are both implemented on top of the same parser, and can be switched between easily using [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) and [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom), that doesn't mean you can simply call methods which work on one on objects created by the other.

In your case, you are primarily using the DOM, so you need to add your attribute using the appropriate DOM functions, specifically [`->createAttributeNS()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattributens.php) and `->appendChild()`.

I think the code you need is this:

```
$ParskCeturksnis = $DOM->createElement('ParskCeturksnis');
$ParskCeturksnis->appendChild($DOM->createAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:nil"));
$DokPVNv4->appendChild($ParskCeturksnis);
```

Comment: By the way. Also used (modified) example from here http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4219487.htm @NomikOS answer at the bottom of page. `xmlns` changed to `xsi:nil` and `'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` to `true`. All works...